# Laravel ошибка на несуществующей странице

Tags: laravel, redirect

Вообщем. Сайт на Laravel. При переходе на практически любую несуществующую страницу, сайт выдает ошибку(как на картинке), а не перенаправляет на 404. Подскажите, где искать ошибку.[image: ошибка]

Comment: По видимому, в `/resources/views/layout.blade.php`

Comment: т.е при переходах по разным несуществующим ссылкам - всегда выдаёт эту ошибку? или ошибки бывают разные?

Comment: ошибка одна и та же. эта переменная отвечает за информацию о пользователе, она работает на главной странице, а когда перехожу на страницу виду site.com/fafa то выдает такую ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Решение простое надо создать свой 404 шаблон и вставить в resoursec/views/errors/
под видом 404.blade.php